# How to show Bottom App Bar after Scrolling while navigating to other fragment?

Tags: android, material-design

I have implemented Bottom App Bar in my application. I am able to hide the Bottom App Bar while scrolling but when I navigate to other fragment it is still hidden? How to make visible Bottom App Bar programatically?

According to Material Design Documentation, I have defined following attribute in Bottom App Bar.

```
app:hideOnScroll="true"
```

And in Fragment I have put scrolling content in NestedScrollView as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Admin.AddUpdateCustomerFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:transitionName="transtion_name_example"
    >

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">


        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**AdminActivity.java**

```
public class AdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public BottomAppBar bottomAppBar;
    public FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(null);
        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        bottomAppBar = (BottomAppBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);
        setSupportActionBar(bottomAppBar);
        new CustomerFragment().setArguments(Bundle.EMPTY);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new CustomerFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    public boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment, Bundle bundle) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**CustomerFragment.java**

```
public class CustomerFragment extends Fragment {
    View rootView;

    public CustomerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer_fragment_admin, container, false);

        ((AdminActivity) getActivity()).bottomAppBar.setFabAlignmentMode(BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_CENTER);
        ((AdminActivity) getActivity()).floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp);
        ((AdminActivity) getActivity()).floatingActionButton.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);

        ((AdminActivity) getActivity()).floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((AdminActivity) getActivity()).loadFragment(new AddUpdateCustomerFragment(), Bundle.EMPTY);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

**AddUpdateCustomerFragment.java**

```
public class AddUpdateCustomerFragment extends Fragment {
    View rootView;

    public AddUpdateCustomerFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_update_customer, container, false);

        ((AdminActivity) getActivity()).bottomAppBar.setNavigationIcon(null);
        ((AdminActivity) getActivity()).bottomAppBar.setFabAlignmentMode(FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_END);

        btnBack = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.back);

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((AdminActivity) getActivity()).loadFragment(new CustomerFragment(), Bundle.EMPTY);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code? That would be nice :)

Comment: Pls post the code in your answer and format it. Kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have edited my post with code

Comment: This may sound irritating, but we don't need to see your XML file, but your Java/Kotlin code.

Comment: But there is no role of Java code in scrolling. I have achieved it using XML.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the solution?

Comment: Please check I have updated question with Java code.

Comment: Put it inside an answer to that other users can see it too. :)

Comment: And don't forget to mark it as "Answered" :)

Comment: No man I have not got answer yet..My issue is bottom app bar is still hidden if I navigate back to other fragment

Comment: @BhhavyaPatel Have you tried to move your bottom navigation bar related code to onResume() so that it can be updated every time you switch from one fragment to another?

Comment: You can create some method (i.e. initBottomNav()) where you can set your bottomAppBar parameters. If it doesn't help, please try to also add  .bottomAppBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and do bottomAppBar.invalidate() (or {your activity's root view id}.invalidate() to force update layout rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround for your problem.

Attach an `OnScrollChangeListener` to your `NestedScrollView` to toggle the Visibility of your `BottomNavBar`

```
scroller.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

        if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Scroll DOWN");
            mBottomNavBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Scroll UP");
            mBottomNavBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (scrollY == 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "TOP SCROLL");
        }

       if (scrollY == ( v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight() )) {
           Log.i(TAG, "BOTTOM SCROLL");
       }
   }
});
```

Inside `onCreateView()` of your fragment, toggle the `Visibility` of your `BottomNavigationBar` and in order to hide it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...
    bottomNavBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
}
```

Or do the same when launching a new `Fragment`:

```
 btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((AdminActivity) getActivity()).loadFragment(new CustomerFragment(), Bundle.EMPTY);
            mBottomNavBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

**And don't forget to remove** `app:hideOnScroll="true"`

Comment: and How can I achieve same in case of ListView with NestedScrollView??

Comment: You have to be specific, do you want to hide the BottomBar on the scroll of `ListView` or on the scroll gesture of `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: In one of of my fragment I have listview